# Galaxy S3 showing messages are not sending when they are

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Title says it all to be honest

Have a galaxy s3 rooted stock jelly bean 4.3

I've been doing some mods recently (not my own just downloaded)
I've undone the most recent ones I've done as only recently the problems started
Haven't you done a restore via CWM as don't want to completely lose the changes I've made

But text messages are sending but always showing up as sending icon (not actually sent)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Which messaging app are you using?

Comment: Contact+ but same thing happening with stock, I restored a backup using CWM which resolved the issue, now just to find what caused it